# Displaying a PowerBI tile in a C# XAML app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, powerbi

I am looking at the tutorial at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt450498.aspx#gettile) on displaying PowerBI tiles in a web app.  I want to do a similar thing in a C# XAML app.

I am able to retrieve all the information about the dashboards and the tiles (including the embedUrl) and I am passing the embedUrl as the source to a WebView element in my XAML app but I don't see anything displayed in the WebView.

I know that I am missing something - the portion mentioned in "Step 2 – Submit authentication token" - where the accesstoken is passed back in the JavaScript function postActionLoadTile.

More specifically, the example on that link has some HTML/JS code like the following for a web app:

```
iframe.src = embedTileUrl + "&width=" + width + "&height=" + height;
```

and

```
iframe.onload = postActionLoadTile;

// post the auth token to the iFrame. 
function postActionLoadTile() {
    // get the access token.
    accessToken = document.getElementById('MainContent_accessTokenTextbox').value;

    // return if accessToken is empty
    if ("" === accessToken)
        return;

    var h = height;
    var w = width; 

    // construct the push message structure
    var m = { action: "loadTile", accessToken: accessToken, height: h, width: w};
    message = JSON.stringify(m);

    // push the message.
    iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameEmbedTile');
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");;
}
```

I am trying to do a similar thing in XAML using the following code:

XAML:

```
<WebView x:Name="myWebView" FrameDOMContentLoaded="myWebView_FrameDOMContentLoaded"/>
```

C#:

```
var str = string.Format(@"<iframe width='{0}' height='{1}' src='{2}'></iframe>", 
            myWebView.ActualWidth - 10,
            myWebView.ActualHeight - 10, 
            struri);

        myWebView.NavigateToString(str);
```

But I don't know how to go beyond that.  I do I replicate all the things happening in the JavaScript code in the C# code.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there an error? What is your code precisely sending to the server? Has it authenticated correctly? Have you used Fiddler to track results?

Comment: First of all, there's probably no point putting an iframe inside your WebView. Second, you aren't initializing the tile. And third, you haven't shown how you are retrieving the auth token.

If you look at the JS code, it is navigating an iframe to the embed URL, *then* it is posting a message to the iframe/window, which presumably the embed code is waiting for. That message tells it what to do (load the tile with certain dimensions), and provides it the authentication token. You don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: I'm evaluating Power BI. Thank you for posting this question. It highlights just what a mess things are. Welcome to the Data Visualization and Reporting Tool for Enterprise Developers that requires you as an Enterprise Developer to completely abandon your XAML/VB/C# skillset, revert to javascript/typescript/css/nodejs and jump through hoops to integrate with typical enterprise apps. Smells like someone who doesn't understand their customer got put in charge of Power BI product development. This is disappointing at best. What solution did you settle on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've figured out how to get an OAuth token and get an embed URL for a tile.

I worked up a basic proof of concept of how to do this by including some JS script in the WebView contents and using the `WebView.InvokeScriptAsync` method to invoke the script.

Here's a gist of the important bits of my solution: https://gist.github.com/itsananderson/14a179174ea65e246ce7

Here is a quick summary:

```C#
private void SetEmbedUrl(string embedUrl)
{
    myWebView.NavigateToString("<iframe id=\"iFrameEmbedTile\" src =\""
        + embedUrl +
        "\" style=\"width: 400px; height: 405px\"></iframe>" +
        "<script src=\"ms-appx-web:///postActionLoadTile.js\"></script>");
}

private void myWebView_FrameDOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("postActionLoadTile", new[] { myTextBox.Text, "400", "400" });
}
```

This references the following postActionLoadTile.js file, which you should add to your project.

```js
function postActionLoadTile(accessToken, h, w) {
  // Generate a message for the iframe
  var m = { action: "loadTile", accessToken: accessToken, height: h, width: w };
  var message = JSON.stringify(m);

  // Push the message to the iframe
  var iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameEmbedTile');
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
}
```

Comment: Hi how can I port this to Windows Forms application with webBrowserContol. I tried. But I didnt get anything